# How do I dump a variable that is too big for dump(var)?

Tags: theming, 8

I am working with the views-view-unformatted.html.twig file, and I am trying to use the following code.

```
{{ dump(row.content | keys) }}
```

The returned value is the following.

```
/var/www/html/example_site/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Debug.php:60:
array (size=5)
  0 => string '#theme' (length=6)
  1 => string '#view' (length=5)
  2 => string '#options' (length=8)
  3 => string '#row' (length=4)
  4 => string '#field_alias' (length=12)
```

With `{{ dump(row.content['#row'] | keys) }}` I get the following.

```
/var/www/html/example_site/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Debug.php:60:
array (size=0)
  empty
```

Based on it being empty, I assume it is not an array and proceed to use `{{ dump(row.content['#row']) }}`. When I do this I get a *504 Gateway Timeout* error. `max_execution_time` is set to 30.

How do I dump a variable that is too big for dump(var)?

Comment: why are you debugging in template and not in preprocess with xdebug?

Comment: Don't have xdebug configured on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, until Kint will be configurable via UI see [#2405179](https://www.drupal.org/node/2405179), edit ***modules/devel/kint/kint/config.default.php*** and set `$_kintSettings['maxLevels']` to a lower number (the default is 7).

Try using 4. This will limit the depth of the array that gets dumped.

Comment: sometimes the solution to a problem, is to just prevent it from happening, right?

Answer (score 0):

A good way to get around twig's limits is to add the preprocess function referenced in the twig debug HTML comments.  Then use kint to dump the information.

If you are doing something that is called a lot of times and kint is overflowing memory, just add a global counter and limit the output to one or two items.  Something like:

```
$mymod_$kint_count = 0;
function mymod_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  global $mymod_kint_count;
  if ( $mymod_kint_count++ < 1 ) {
    kint($variables);
  }
}
```

Note: You will need the kint module and dev enabled for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use of {{ dsm(row.content) }} will solve your problem. This code takes a little time irrespective of how much data, displays it all.